# Search for a word in the first 7character in each row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to look for "nFormat" but just in the begin (just in the first 7 characters). If I found it, I need to look at the last character from the line above, if it is not @ I need to write it and put both line together

My program is:

```
Sub Line_Config()

Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Prow As Long
Dim atual As String
Dim nextRow As String
Dim fGet As Range
Dim fnFormat As Range
Dim fa As Range

With Sheets("Get_Command")
.Select

Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

' Start the loop
For Lrow = Lastrow To 2 Step -1

    Prow = Lrow - 1

    Set fGet = Cells(Lrow, 1).Find("Get:", LookIn:=xlValues)

        If fGet Is Nothing Then 'If Get: is not found

        Set fnFormat = Cells(Lrow, 1).Find("nFormat", LookIn:=Left(Cells(Lrwo, 1), 7))

            If Not fnFormat Is Nothing Then 'If nFormat is found

            Set fa = Cells(Prow, 1).Find("@", LookIn:=Right(Cells(Prow, 1), 1))

                If fa Is Nothing Then

                    atual = Cells(Lrow, 1).Value
                    nextRow = Cells(Prow, 1).Value + "@" + atual

                    Cells(Prow, 1).FormulaR1C1 = nextRow
                    Cells(Lrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete

                End If

            Else

            atual = Cells(Lrow, 1).Value
            nextRow = Cells(Prow, 1).Value + atual

            Cells(Prow, 1).FormulaR1C1 = nextRow
            Cells(Lrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        End If

Next Lrow

.Columns("A").Replace _
What:="@", Replacement:=" ", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

End With

End Sub
```

Excel told me the error is in:

```
 Set fnFormat = Cells(Lrow, 1).Find("nFormat", LookIn:=Left(Cells(Lrwo, 1), 7))
```

How can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: why do you use `Find` for single cell? why not just compare: `If Left(Cells(Lrwo, 1), 7)="nFormat" Then`?

Comment: Thanks, I start to work with vba just for a 2 weeks... I didn't tought to do like this! =)

Comment: I change the way you told, but it still not running, it show this line now and says: Run-time error '1004' Application-Defined or Object-defined error!

Comment: the same thing with `Set fa = Cells(Prow, 1).Find("@", LookIn:=Right(Cells(Prow, 1), 1))`. Change to `If Right(Cells(Prow, 1), 1)="@" Then`

Comment: I found the error... It should see just into the value: If Left(Cells(Lrwo, 1).Value, 7)="nFormat" Then  Thank you Simoco! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error for this call

```
Set fnFormat = Cells(Lrow, 1).Find("nFormat", LookIn:=Left(Cells(Lrwo, 1), 7))
```

Because the parameter LookIn is not used to define a range to use the `Find` command on, but it is used to define whether to look in values or formulas in that range.
LookIn can assume the values of the enumeration `XlFindLookIn` : `xlComments`, `xlFormulas` and `xlValues`.

You should use the [`InStr(Start, String1, String2, Compare)` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Dim tString as String
tString = Left(Cells(Lrow, 1).Value, 7)
If InStr(1, "nFormat", tString, Compare:=vbTextCompare) > 0) then
  'nFormat was found, do stuff
End If
```